# In JasperStudio, I need to display the text on (n-1)th page alone

Tags: jasper-reports

In `JasperStudio`, I need to display the text only on (n-1)th page. unfortunately I am unable to do that.

I have tried doing it with variables below

```
<variable name="nthpage" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="None">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

and

```
<variable name="n-1thpage" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="None">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[($V{PAGE_NUMBER}-1)]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

and for the report text field expression used as

```
<textField evaluationTime="Report">
    <reportElement x="383" y="124" width="136" height="16" uuid="3193a49a-7354-44c2-a5e7-62336419a190"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{n-1thpage}==($V{nthpage})?"Hi":"Hello"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

I have tried with `evaluationTime="Auto"`. But it's not working for me.

**How can I achieve this custom behavior?**

Comment: could you format the code better?

Comment: hi zedd, xml has been formed above while I designed the report. xml structure as code I got. I'm using ireport 5.5. I don't know what's happening on internal in jasper.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Print When Expression` e.g. to print a report element on the 10th page only fill the `Print When Expression` with the value `$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 10`

Comment: sure Robert. but it'll work for 10 pages only. right? if pages are dynamic means it'll not work. right?

Comment: It will work fine - just pass a variable to the expression e.g. $V{PAGE_NUMBER} == $V{YOUR_VARIABLE}